# Android 2.2.3 - long delay after phone call end

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls

There's a long delay between the call end (even when I press "End Call" button) and when I can use the notification bar again for example.

The in-call green phone icon stays in the notification bar for another few seconds.

Is there anything I can do about this, please?

Comment: Dunno, but I think yours is typical. I have to wait at least a few seconds before my DROID is "released" after a call. Fortunately I don't make too many phone calls.

Comment: Haha, make / receive it's the same thing. Also, the 2.3.3 distribution is not rooted or touched in anyway. Well... except what Samsung did to it...

Comment: Same here on a Sensation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual Android disconnection response.

It's to do with your phone checking in with the closest Antenna when you end a call.

Perhaps this will help explain the speed a little:

http://images.cellphones.org/cell_phone_calls.jpg

p.s. I just hit end call then home or lock screen and put it in my pocket :-)

Comment: I do hit End Call, well, not hit, but gently touch, but the screen stays for a while. I just want to make sure the call is closed so I can say bad things about the person that just called. :)

Comment: Hehe yeah the 'call is closed' i.e. your mic is not taking input as soon as you gently touch end call.